# Activator.CreateInstance(string) and Activator.CreateInstance<T>() difference

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

No, this is not a question about generics.

I have a Factory pattern with several classes with internal constructors (I don't want them being instantiated if not through the factory).

My problem is that `CreateInstance` fails with a "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" error unless I pass "true" on the non-public parameter.

Example

```
// Fails
Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Works
Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
```

I wanted to make the factory generic to make it a little simpler, like this:

```
public class GenericFactory<T> where T : MyAbstractType
{
    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

However, I was unable to find how to pass that "true" parameter for it to accept non-public constructors (internal).

Did I miss something or it isn't possible?

Comment: Why not define a parameterless constructor with the private boolean variable set to true?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get around this, couldnt you just alter your usage as such:

```
public class GenericFactory<T> where T : MyAbstractType
{
    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);
    }
}
```

Your factory method will still be generic, but the call to the activator will not use the generic overload. But you should still achieve the same results.

Comment: If the overload doesn't exist, I would have to say no.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely require that the constructor be private you can try something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericFactory<T> where T : MyAbstractType
{
    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you're best off adding the new constraint and going that route:

```
public abstract class GenericFactory<T> where T : MyAbstractType, new()
{
    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        return new T;
    }
}
```

You're trying to use GenericFactory as a base class for all of your factories rather than writing each from scratch right?

Comment: The first option is the same as that of Kilhoffer

The second won't work, adding new() to the where requires the type to have a public parameter, which is exactly what I don't want

Comment: Yeah, his post appeared as I was typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

besides Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) to work, T should have default constructor