# Activator.CreateInstance vs Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory, createinstance

What is the difference between `Activator.CreateInstance` and factory? Can they be used interchangeably? Or stil do we need a factory pattern?

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance will instantiate an object for you from a type. It can very well be incorporated into a Factory pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factory pattern is a higher-level pattern.  It gives you a structure in which you can address some issues that can occur with object creation.  To quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern),

> The creation of an object often
>   requires complex processes not
>   appropriate to include within a
>   composing object. The object's
>   creation may lead to a significant
>   duplication of code, may require
>   information not accessible to the
>   composing object, may not provide a
>   sufficient level of abstraction, or
>   may otherwise not be part of the
>   composing object's concerns.
>
> Some of the processes required in the
>   creation of an object include
>   determining which object to create,
>   managing the lifetime of the object,
>   and managing specialized build-up and
>   tear-down concerns of the object.

Activator.CreateInstance doesn't address any of these issues, it merely allows you to create a new instance of a type.  If you don't have issues like the above (and many uses of the "factory pattern" aren't in the context of such issues), Activator.CreateInstance will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

[`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) is a static method that creates an instance of the specified type using that type's default constructor.

While [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) deals with the problem of creating objects (products) without specifying the exact class of object that will be created.

You can "use" the `Activator.CreateInstance` within a factory pattern to return different types of objects. [See this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mbouck/GenericDataAccessCompActivator09052005013346AM/GenericDataAccessCompActivator.aspx). You can also [create a generic factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439/activator-createinstancestring-and-activator-createinstancet-difference/57450#57450) utilizing `Activator.CreateInstance`