# How to use materialskin without external dll

Tags: c#, nuget

I looked and I did find a few questions similar but wasn't clear enough
Q: How would I use the MaterialSkin NuGet package without needing the external DLL that has to be in the folder of the project for it to work?
I have seen it done before

Comment: It's open source rit?. Then why don't you just get the code from GITHUB and include it inside your solution under one of your projects?.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is make a self-extracting exe file but instead of running an installer, it would instead extract your application files to the temp directory and run the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an assembly AND reference it (in VS) at the same time... for the way you want to use it you need to reference it! Any reason you don't reference the Assembly ?

Using a Type from an embedded Assembly (managed) without referencing it is a bit harder but possible using Reflection etc. -

You can refer more on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228423/how-to-use-an-dll-load-from-embed-resource) Post on how to embed and use types from embedded resources but it's way harder to use types from embedded dll's