# How to declare type in an Imported or Embed Resource DLL

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, embed, dllimport

I'm actually looking for solution merge all DLL and EXE into single file.

I have asked a question at here:

> > [How to use an DLL load from Embed Resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228423/how-to-use-an-dll-load-from-embed-resource)

and I received suggestion that I can link the DLL as embed resource, then write the embed DLL file into memory and use DLLImport to import the DLL.

I followed the instructions here:

> > http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/02/04/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code.aspx

and below is what I have done:

```
[DllImport("System.Data.SQLite.dll")]
public static SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection1 = new SQLiteConnection();

public Form1()
{
    ResourceExtractor.ExtractResourceToFile("MyApp.System.Data.SQLite.dll", "System.Data.SQLite.dll");
}

public static class ResourceExtractor
{
    public static void ExtractResourceToFile(string resourceName, string filename)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        using (System.IO.Stream s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
            fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

but Visual Studio says that this block creates an error:

```
[DllImport("System.Data.SQLite.dll")]
public static SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection1 = new SQLiteConnection();
```

*Error  1   Attribute 'DllImport' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method' declarations.*

How to declare the type inside that DLL?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: DllImport is only for unmanaged code, which would also need an extern keyword here.

Comment: Since your program here only uses managed code the blog you followed is for a different problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DllImport` is only for native DLLs.

On embedding managed DLLs you have several options:

- use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) (free)
  For howto see [here](https://github.com/Tigraine/dotless/blob/master/default.ps1#L87) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

OR

- use some tool like [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) (commercial)
  it can embed and merge among other things (no need to change your source code)

OR

- [code that yourself in less than 10 lines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) (free but minimal source code change)
  mark all needed dependencies as "embedded resource" - this way they are included in the EXE file... you need to setup an [`AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) handler which at runtime reads from Resources and returns the needed DLLs to the .NET runtime...

On using a type from such an Assembly see these links (they including reference material AND some sample code etc.):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450/847363
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx (loads an ssembly from a byte array so there is no need to write that assembly to the filesystem)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a

Answer (score 2):

The `DllImport` attribute is used to declare methods from unmanaged DLLs.

Since `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is a managed assembly, what you need to do, after saving your assembly to disk, is to load it via `Reflection`, something like:

```
using System.Data;
...

var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"path\to\System.Data.SQLite.dll");
var type = assembly.GetType("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection");
IDbConnection connection = (IDbConnection)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stuff managed assemblies and the exe in one file, I suggest you look at [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

It is much easier to use than manually doing things with resources.